# Questions on Bode Plot and Nyquist Plot

Tags: pole-zeroplot, nyquist-plot

**Bode Plot**

1) Why the gain plot |G(jw)| drops and then increases for conjugate zeroes ?

2) Why the gain plot |G(jw)| increases and then drops for conjugate poles ?

**Nyqust Plot**

3) For Figure 9-18(B), could anyone explain in a bit more details than the book as on how to obtain the following Nyquist plot pattern ?

[image: conjugate zeros]

[image: conjugate poles]

[image: Nyquist Plot]

Comment: Does Figure 9-18 have a particular transfer function? I feel like all of your questions can be answered if you have the appropriate textbook material. I don't think taking a powerpoint by its word is good learning material. Do you have a book on control theory? If not, then I have plenty to recommend.

Comment: For Bode, let \$s \rightarrow j\omega\$ and then find the magnitudes of the resultant complex expressions. For Nyquist, plot imaginary against real.

Comment: @Chu I know s=jw , the question is why there is trough / peak for the case of conjugate zero / conjugate poles respectively ?

Comment: @KingDuken I have understood the nyquist plot for figure 9-18(b)

Comment: If you determine the expression for magnitude, you'll find a maximum at a particular value of \$\omega\$ in the case of complex poles, and a minimum in the case of complex zeroes.

Comment: @Chu Why the [gain expression for the case of conjugate zeros](https://i.imgur.com/jrdRoPF.png) does not imply a trough at wd ?

Comment: The Bode Plots can be derived from Root Locus by an vector sweep of curves with frequency and location of a 3rd order will have resonant and anti resonant responses depending on C ratios with L

Comment: It **does** have a minimum.

Comment: @Chu huh ? How can be so sure without doing it mathematically ?

Comment: I have done the maths. For \$\zeta \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\$ there is a minimum at \$\omega = \omega _n \sqrt{(1-2\zeta ^2)}\$. The minimum for \$\zeta \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\$ is at \$\omega =0\$. There must be an error in your analysis if you find different.

Comment: @Chu [The trough should be at wn instead of wd, I presume.](https://i.imgur.com/ic8anwK.png)

Comment: Minimum is at \$\omega _r\$.

Comment: @Chu What do you mean by wr ?

Comment: Resonant frequency = \$\omega _r = \omega _n \sqrt{1-2\zeta^2}\$; damped natural frequency =  \$\omega _d = \omega _n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\$; where \$\omega_n\$ is the natural frequency. All this stuff is on the web!

Comment: @Chu wait, what was wrong with my calculation above ?

Comment: Minimum is given by: \$\frac{d}{d\omega}((\omega^2_n-\omega^2)^2+4\zeta^2\omega^2_n \omega^2)=0\$. This gives two minima, one (at \$\omega = \omega_r\$) for \$\zeta \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\$ and the other (at \$\omega =0\$) for \$\zeta > \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\$

Comment: ... there is no resonant frequency (i.e. no stationary point) for a standard 2nd order TF for damping coefficient values, \$\zeta > \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\$